# Redux prevent unwanted effect

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Hello**

How i prevent this effect:

The effect that i want:
[image: Capture-d-e-cran-2020-10-23-a-17-00-43.png]

But on dispatching the same action with multiple product and then the product are not in the lated position of array ( this will be unwanted effect because i need to go to another page and comeback to cart to see the effect ):
[image: Capture-d-e-cran-2020-10-23-a-17-05-10.png]

I have upload a video that describe better the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1miZA4B1Ay5OZZBGPj1bCcQHsGv21oVW_/view

Comment: Got it, some code would be appreciated bro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502691/redux-and-react-unwanted-effect

Comment: I'm sorry to repost but no one help :( at the least post

Answer (score 0):

In the video you deleted the first item in the cart but the second item disappeared and the first still shows up.  In the screenshot of your store, you see that actually we did delete the first item and the second item moved into the first position, which is what we want.  So the dispatch action is going through just fine and having the intended effect.

That means the problem exists in getting the data out of the store and displaying it in your app.  The app recognized that the array changed from length 2 to length 1, but it didn't recognize the the contents of `array[0]` have changed.

You might be memoizing something and missing a dependency, either in react or in a memoized selector.  It seems like you might be memoizing based on the array index rather than the contents of the array.

Somewhere along the line you have decided to use a sparse array for the cart because in your first screenshot there is only one item but its index is `2`.  Was that intentional?  Why?

Comment: Hello the problem has been fixed by changing index key by my own unique index

Comment: Now if I want to remove the first or another item from my cart who them are not in the last position of key, redux and react know well what I want to delete, but the problem is react side not redux